# Finding the radius of convergence of a series

Tags: real-analysis

How do I find the radius of convergence of a series such as:

$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{n^2}}{2^n}
$$

If this was $$\frac{x^{n}}{2^n}$$I would try to find $$\frac{1}{R}=limsup\frac{1}{2^n}^{1/n}$$

I feel I'm missing something painfully obvious...

Comment: use mathjax to edit your post

Answer (score 1):

Hint. Your series is $\sum a_m x^m$ where
$$
a_m =
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{2^{\sqrt{m}}}, &\text{if $m$ is a perfect square}\\
0, &\text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$$
Now it shouldn't be difficult to compute $\limsup_m a_m^{1/m}$.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\frac1R=\limsup_{n\to\infty}\Bigl(\frac{1}{2^n}\Bigr)^{1/n^2}=\limsup_{n\to\infty}2^{-1/n}=?
$$